# Dynamically loading interactive SVGs into Vue.js project

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, vue.js

I have an old project built years ago with spaghetti jQuery code, which I'd like to update to use a JS framework (mostly for the usual reasons: better scaleability, better state management, cleaner/more maintainable code, etc.). I find Vue.js especially intriguing.

The project allows the user to load any of a large selection of .svg files from a directory on the server into the DOM dynamically, then interact with them (mostly clicking to change fill/line colors of individual path elements, handled by jQuery plus a [plugin](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html)).

After some research and experimentation, I haven't found a simple way to do this with Vue--as best I can tell, I would need to manually edit each .svg file to put the (many) bindings in place to allow for discrete parts of the .svg to have interactivity. This is a dealbreaker due to the large number of files and the need to quickly add new ones.

My vague question (sorry) is: can anyone point me toward a better solution? (A framework better suited to this? A way in Vue to replicate this kind of interactivity with a plain .svg? A way to automate modifying the .svg files to have Vue bindings on their arbitrary numbers/types of svg elements?)

Thanks--

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way in Vue to add interactivity is to [convert them to components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/editable-svg-icons.html)
but this **won't work** in your situation because the svg's are uploaded by users.

So you'll need to find or write a component that adds this feature to your app.

Take a look at https://github.com/seiyable/vue-simple-svg for inspiration.